# How to disable `Fast Refresh` in React native on Javascript (not using Developer Menu)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Fast Refresh is broken in some Detox tests and I need to disable it from Javascript, without using the Developer Menu.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer in the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/d72e078df41f1ba2eb94e4eb4fb28b8d0232a8a1/Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings.js#L20)

For version `0.61`:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

if (__DEV__) {
  const { DevSettings } = NativeModules;
  DevSettings.setHotLoadingEnabled(false);
  DevSettings.setLiveReloadEnabled(false);
}
```

For version >= `0.62`:

```
import { DevSettings } from "react-native"

if (__DEV__) {
  DevSettings._nativeModule.setHotLoadingEnabled(false);
}
```

For version >= `0.71`:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

if (__DEV__) {
  NativeModules.DevSettings.setHotLoadingEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: This puts my app in a restart loop. I have written it at the beginning of the file where my App component is defined.

Comment: Outside the component definition, right? Which version of React Native are you using?

Comment: Here is a reproduction project for expo and endless loop: https://github.com/denniske/expo-no-fast-refresh. I also created a new project in snack. There the fast refresh works even when disabled: https://snack.expo.io/@denniske1001/a68b19

Comment: This code worked for React-Native but I never tested on Expo, maybe it doesn't work... Probably they are doing things differently

Comment: For React Native 0.62.2, `DevSettings` is no longer available in `NativeModules`, so import directly with `import { DevSettings } from "react-native"` and consume the function with `DevSettings._nativeModule.setHotLoadingEnabled(false)`. `setLiveReloadEnabled()` is [no longer available](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.62-stable/Libraries/NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings.js)

Comment: For me none of these work with RN 0.63. Also disabling Fast Refresh from the debug menu does nothing, and it stupidely keeps reloading on each file change.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to disabled fast-refresh in expo. Is there some setting somewhere where I can do this ?

Answer (score 3):

For React Native 0.63, it seems like something broke with the accepted answer. However, just toggling the property makes it work:

```js
import { DevSettings } from "react-native"

if (__DEV__) {
  DevSettings._nativeModule.setHotLoadingEnabled(true);
  DevSettings._nativeModule.setHotLoadingEnabled(false);
}
```

I'm curious if this works for others.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with RN 0.63.4 and fixed that by adding a patch.
I noticed this is already fixed in 0.64.0 version and here [is the PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/845e9eaafb08b4ca87a9987e840798e0ba011676).
you can either upgrade or add a patch to fix this. this worked for me.